# Active JQuery resource/directory with RSS news feed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to be updated every day with the latest JQuery news and new releases of plugins. Any active JQuery web resource with an RSS feed which I can subscribe to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. http://blog.jquery.com
2. [John Resig's Blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/)
3. [The jQuery Podcast](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=339835419) on iTunes
4. [@jQuery](http://twitter.com/jquery) on Twitter
5. Karl Swedberg's [LearningjQuery.com](http://learningjquery.com)
6. Remy Sharp's [jQueryForDesigners.com](http://jqueryfordesigners.com)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [@jquery Twitter feed](http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/14538601.rss). It won't be totally comprehensive, but it's certainly a good starting place.